# New website - How do they know my personal information?

Tags: security

A newbie here, so please bear with me. I registered a domain with a big hosting company.

A few days ago, I noticed I started getting emails directly to my personal email with my full name. I started searching up my website and found a website who shows all my personal information. The exact full address where I live, my full name and my phone number.

Do personal information like that suddenly go all public when I register a domain, without my permission? A little bit worried if it's supposed to be like that, so I'm just asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register a domain, your contact information is published in the WHOIS service. You can use a [WHOIS lookup tool](http://whois.icann.org/en) and enter your domain name to see what the registration says. Anyone on the Internet can see the same thing.

Many domain registrars offer a privacy filtering service. They will obscure that information and put up their own name, address, etc. ([Look up my domain](http://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=tangledhelix.com), `tangledhelix.com`, for an example of what that might look like.) Some registrars will charge you for this, while others offer it for free or bundled with hosting or something else they sell.

Of course, it is too late to pull back the publication of the information now, but you can add a privacy shield service (if your registrar offers one) and stop the leakage from going further.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I have made a support ticket at my hosting company's website. But isn't it unlawful to use WHOIS information to contact the website admins personally to advertise for webdesign jobs?

Comment: I think most whois lookup services have a disclaimer saying you can't use the data for this or that use... I doubt it stops people from doing it anyway, though.